# Rails 4 - CSS is not being applied in production

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I am trying to make a rails 4 app. I use bootstrap and SCSS.

In my gem file I have:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.5.1'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 4.4.0'
gem 'bootstrap-slider-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'
```

In my stylesheets folder, I have several folders, one is called application.css.scss

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap-slider";



@import "addresses.scss";
@import "articles.css.scss";
@import "common.css.scss";
@import "footer.css.scss";
@import "forms.css.scss";
@import "glyphs.css.scss";
@import "index.css.scss";
@import "legal.css.scss";
@import "navigation.css.scss";
@import "pages.css.scss";
@import "profiles.scss";
@import "video.css.scss";
```

In my articles.css.scss file I have:

```
.commentattributiondate {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: grey;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-align:right;
  padding-right: 10%;
  padding-top:1%;
  line-height: 1.5;

}
```

In my view, I have:

```
<div class="commentattributiondate">
                    <%= comment.created_at.try(:strftime, '%e %B %Y') %>
                </div>
```

In local host, my text is formatted using this style.

However, in production mode it is not. When I inspect the element in google, I can see that the date is wrapped in this div tag and it is the closest div tag to the attribute, however, when I want to inspect the style in the code inspector, that div tag name isn't listed at all.

I previously had a problem with styling saved in files that were higher in alphabetical order than the application.css.scss file, however, articles comes after application and is imported in the application file.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

In fact, the same is true for all of the styling defined in my profiles.css.scss file as well.

Comment: How do you "inspect the element in google"?  Google is a search engine.

Comment: Hi Cimmanon, when you right click on the html, you can choose inspect. That shows you the html used on the page

Comment: @cimmanon I think he meant on the browser

Comment: @user2860931I'm no RAILS expert, and this may not be your answer (hence why I'm not providing it as an answer) but shouldn't your file naming be file.scss or _file.scss if it's a partial file? Instead of file.css.scss?

Comment: Hi lotusms, they're not partials. Thanks anyway

Comment: @user2860931, ok, but my point was should you be writing it file.scss instead of file.css.scss? Or is that how it's supposed to be imported in RAILS?

Comment: Hi - there are lots of different opinions on that. I tried making profiles.scss (without the css) but I get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I don't know why it isn't automatic in the push to heroku, but hope it helps others:

In production.rb - uncomment this line:

```
config.assets.css_compressor = :sass
```

Then:

```
rake assets:precompile
```